# how can the MessageListenerContainer listen the message asynchronously?

Tags: jms

Is there any long-lasting TCP connecton be set up? Any TCP port be open for this to work?

Comment: Fairly poorly asked question with little context or details on what's really being sought.

Answer (score 0):

From the [spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jms.html)

> A message listener container is the intermediary between an MDP and a messaging provider

MessageListenerContainer is some glue code. The real interesting stuff is going on in the JMS provider.  And yes, it almost certainly involves a TCP connection or something similar.

The specifics are an implementation detail.  Consult your JMS vendor documentation and maybe they'll spell it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Spring's message listener container (but you haven't stated that), it takes the connection from the injected *connectionFactory* property, so you need to examine the `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` implementation of your JMS provider to give you a clue. It may or may not be over TCP. It may well be embedded inside the same JVM, in a test setup, for example.